# How to calculate the derivative of a sequence (discrete function) with respect to another discrete function?

Tags: discrete-signals, derivative, deep-learning

In [Learning Recursive Filters for Low-Level Vision via a Hybrid Neural Network](https://faculty.ucmerced.edu/mhyang/papers/eccv16_rnn_filter.pdf), the hidden state of the recurrent neural network (RNN), after some simplification, presented as

$$
h[k] = (1-p)\cdot x[k] + p \cdot h[k-1].
$$

Then it is stated that the derivations with respect to $h[k]$, denoted as $\theta[k]$, is as the following:

$$
\theta[k] = \delta[k] + p\cdot \theta[k+1].
$$
I don't understand how this derivative is obtained. Any hint and/or introducing any resources is appreciated.